# How can I divide an array at every second item into an subarray containing these two items

Tags: python

I have a bunch of x- and y-coordinates in a text file, where every second number is a x-/y-coordinate (like shown below). I already wrote the numbers into an array, but now I have to divide the array at every second number into a subarray, containing the x- and y-coordinate. How do I do this?

coordinates.txt

```
 x  y  x  y  x  y
10 30 40 50 60 70
```

Comment: is it correct to assume your array is `[10,30,40,50,60,70]`?

Comment: Can you post the expected output? Also post the code you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your array is always made by x,y pairs, (i.e. len(array) is always a multiple of 2) then you can do something like:

```
a = [10,30,40,50,60,70]
xy_pairs = [a[n:n+2] for n in range(len(a)) if not n%2]

>>> print(xy_pairs)
[[10, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70]]
```

If you want to keep x and y values separated, then you can do:

```
xs = [a[n] for n in range(len(a)) if not n%2]
ys = [a[n] for n in range(len(a)) if n%2]

>>> print(xs)
[10, 40, 60]
>>> print(ys)
[30, 50, 70]
```

The latter can be done also using `enumerate(a)` instead of `range(len(a))` which is considered to be more pythonic.

```
xs = [n for i,n in enumerate(a) if not i%2]
ys = [n for i,n in enumerate(a) if i%2]
```

Comment: `xs = a[::2]; ys = a[1::2]`

Comment: @wwii Great alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily using `zip` and slices:

```
zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2])
```

`numbers[::2]` takes only the even indices (starting at `0` obviously) while `[1::2]` takes the odd ones. `zip` "pairs" the elements of the two lists.

Note that `zip` produces an iterator. If you want to get an actual list call `list` on it:

```
>>> list(zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2]))
[(10, 30), (40, 50), (60, 70)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some itertools magic:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

data = "10 30 40 50 60 70"

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for x,y in grouper(data.split(" "), 2):
    print(x, y)
```

Which yields

```
('10', '30')
('40', '50')
('60', '70')
```

Shamelessly copied from the [**original website**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes), additionally see [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/g1Rn84).

Answer (score 0):

Try the list comprehension method, by using the step size of 2 for the original list.

```
op_list = [10,30,40,50,60,70]
new_list = [[op_list[i], op_list[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(op_list), 2)]
print new_list
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `zip()` with an iterator:

```
l = [10,30,40,50,60,70]

l = iter(l)
l = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(l, l)]
# [[10, 30], [40, 50], [60, 70]]
```